# Batch high score script

Tags: file, batch-file

I have made a memory game in batch and when you lose you submit your score which gets saved in a text file with your name, the points you got, and the date on one line.  What i want to do is have all the entries in that file be ranged from highest point value to lowest.  If i have to take away the date it's fine.

Any suggestions?

Thank-you in advance guys.

Comment: I realize it's cliche to ask, but...what was your question?  Do you have thoughts about how to approach it?  Are you unsure if what you wrote (hint, hint) is valid and correct?  Do you get errors when attempting to execute your code?  Are you confused as to where to start?  Please address these concerns, as it will make helping you and your cause out much simpler.

Comment: I'm asking, is there any way to arrange the text in a text file in order from highest number to least while retaining the other data that is on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a `sort` command which should hopefully be able to re-arrange the file based on your criteria. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sort.mspx?mfr=true) for details.

If that's not powerful enough for your needs, check out the UNIXy sort from [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) in [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html), which may have better support for sorting based on fields (rather than column positions) and numeric data (so that "2" is less than "19").

Comment: Ok i made it work.  The game stores the data like this.. 2-Calder with points then a dash then the name.  They i sorted it in reverse.  Thank-you a bunch!!  I'd plus you but it seems i can't do much with 1 rep in this forum.

Comment: @Calder, you can click on that big green hollow tick mark if the answer is one you want to accept :-)

Comment: I did but accidentally clicked twice so now i have to wait 2 mins XD.  How did i get 6 rep do you know, i'm new here.

Comment: @Calder, you got a down vote (-2) from somebody which had no effect since you were already at the minimum 1. Then I gave you an upvote (worth +5) since I disagreed - I had no (well, little) problems in understanding what you were asking hence the "unclear/not-useful" reason didn't seem apt. The other reason ("no research effort") was a bit more substantial but, in the  end, I err on the side of compassion unless it's plainly obvious the questioner hasn't tried _anything!_

Comment: @Calder, if you're really interested in how all that works, the FAQ is linked at the bottom of the page and there are dozens of entries on meta (also linked at bottom) which will hopefully clarify.

Comment: Thankx.  I did try Google but did not find anything that related to my problem.  i Googled something like "batch arrange text by number".

Comment: is check out the UNIXy sort from CoreUtils in GnuWin32 able to be mobile?  So if i transfer my bat file to another pc it will still work?

Comment: @Calder, yes, unlike something like CygWin, you can simply copy the needed files rather than having to install. Each package/program lists its dependencies.

Comment: ok thx, but i have found a solution already :P  I have my high scores saved in the fork file system.